# Adding a horizontal line between the rows in a latex table using R xtable

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I have a sample latex table generation code like this

```
df<-data.frame(name=rep(letters[1:7],each=24),salary=runif(24*7,100,200))
lst<-tapply(df$salary,df$name,matrix,nrow=4,byrow=T)
xlst<-lapply(lst,xtable)
```

Now I want to introduce \hdashline automatically after every row in every table and **also a \vspace{2em}** in between the tables from R code
Wat I have tried is this

```
for(i in seq_along(lst)){
  addtorow[i] <- list(pos = list(seq_len(nrow(lst[[i]])-1)),
                      command = "\\hdashline \n")
}
```

wat changes do i need to make in for loop..It works when I apply for a single table but not working in a for loop...Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: +1 for posting sample data and code.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than using a loop, consider using the existing `print.xtable` functionality combined with paste.

1. **hdashlines:**  Consider using the `print.xtable` parameters.  For example, there is a parameter `hline.after` that controls horizontal lines between the table lines.
2. **vspace:** This is possibly simpler using `paste`.

For example:

```
library(xtable)
df <- data.frame(name=rep(letters[1:3],each=24),salary=runif(24*3,100,200))
lst <- tapply(df$salary,df$name,matrix,nrow=4,byrow=T)
xlst <- lapply(lst,function(x)print(xtable(x), hline.after=1:nrow(x)))
xlst <- lapply(xlst, paste, "\\vspace{2em}")
xlst
```

> [1] "% latex table generated in R 2.13.1 by xtable 1.5-6 package\n%
>   Tue Aug 23 13:36:41
>   2011\n\begin{table}[ht]\n\begin{center}\n\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}\n
>   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \n 1 & 158.66 & 115.81 & 106.70 & 128.78
>   & 157.43 & 191.01 \\ \n   \hline\n2 & 159.09 & 172.31 & 153.93 &
>   127.91 & 106.93 & 147.95 \\ \n   \hline\n3 & 135.65 & 139.45 &
>   192.90 & 108.78 & 186.52 & 164.10 \\ \n   \hline\n4 & 190.10 &
>   154.39 & 124.91 & 199.24 & 161.99 & 167.61 \\ \n
>   \hline\n\end{tabular}\n\end{center}\n\end{table}\n \vspace{2em}"

---

See `?print.xtable` for more details.  If `hline.after` is not flexible enough for your purposes, then have a look at `add.to.row` where you can specify both the position and exact element type to add.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `print.xtable`, try the following inside `print.xtable`:

`hline.after = rep(c(1:nrow(df)),2)# repeating horizontal lines in xtable`